# Intersecting N width_buckets

Tags: sql, postgresql, intersection

I'm trying to take subsets from bucketed columns, and then take the intersection.

This will select other columns from the original table.

I'm also open to filtering in series.

The code below reports col1 doesn't exist - not sure It's the correct approach anyway.

```
WITH ranges AS (
    SELECT 
    min(col1) AS c1min, 
    max(col1) AS c1max,
    min(col2) AS c2min,
    max(col2) AS c2max
    FROM csv_test
),
f1 AS (
    SELECT width_bucket(col1,c1min,c1max,12) AS b1
    FROM csv_test, ranges 
    ORDER BY b1 ASC
),
f2 AS (
    SELECT width_bucket(col2,c2min,c2max,12) AS b2
    FROM csv_test, ranges 
    ORDER BY b2 ASC
)
SELECT b1, b2, c3, c4, c18
FROM csv_test
WHERE 
b1 BETWEEN 0 AND 5
AND
b2 BETWEEN 3 AND 7;
```

Comment: Do you want something like **[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1ea8a68f0e5fb8eb8db2f98979409bd1)**?

Comment: That is perfect. LATERAL joins were what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LATERAL` join:

```
SELECT t.*, s2.*
FROM csv_test t
,LATERAL (SELECT 
           min(col1) AS c1min, 
           max(col1) AS c1max,
           min(col2) AS c2min,
           max(col2) AS c2max
           FROM csv_test) AS s
,LATERAL (SELECT width_bucket(col1,c1min,c1max,12) AS b1,
                 width_bucket(col2,c2min,c2max,12) AS b2) AS s2
WHERE b1 BETWEEN 0 AND 5
  AND b2 BETWEEN 3 AND 7;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1ea8a68f0e5fb8eb8db2f98979409bd1)**